# extract a field and the link to content from all nodes

Tags: views

i have a content type and it stores user_email,title,body etc.

Every node has a URL alias.

How can i go through all the node, and extract the email field + the URL of that node.

any clue  .
thanks

Comment: you mean you want fetch all email_field and url alias of all nodes?

Comment: Do you want get specify content type?

Comment: yes , i want to fetch all email_field and url alias of all nodes.

Comment: good, do you want get specified content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want get node of `page` content type ,you can try another content types

```
$type = "page"; // machine name for Basic Page
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
$arr=array();
foreach($nodes as $node){
     arr[$node->nid]['email']= $node->field_email['und'][0]['value'];
     arr[$node->nid]['url_alias']= drupal_get_path_alias('node/'. $node->nid);
    }
```

Comment: great. Is there a way that i can put the above code in a file like export.php and run it directly like mywebsite.com/export.php. ?

i dont want to ad it in a template file

Comment: no,you cant put it in .php file , (of course there is way to do it but not recommended),put it in your custom module

Comment: @brainHax  you can create a menu link (mywebsite.com/export) from module using hook_menu and output the array in table format ..using theme() function.. Incase if you dont want it in template.

Answer (score 2):

You can get url of any particular node using this function

```
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/102');
```

Getting email of any node use following statement

```
$node = node_load(102);
$email = $node->field_email['und'][0]['email']
```

Make sure I am getting these details of NodeID 102 in above example.